# How to make a mask of everything outside the result of FindContours()

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I've detected the triangular shape of the traffic sign I want to detect. To use this image for further processing, I'd like to create a mask to make the background white (or black, doesn't really matter).

To detect this shape I used:

```
 VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
 Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

 CvInvoke.FindContours(input.GetImage(), contours, hierarchy,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
```

With the `DrawContours` method, I can easily draw them, with the correct result: [image of the contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC6Rp.png).

How do I make a mask so that I can clear everything outside the contours?

Comment: Draw the contour filled with white into a black image of the same size.

Comment: You have a mask, which is your contours. Just draw nothing but your contours on a new Mat, its the same as masking out everything outside your contours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contours you have and draw to another similar empty image if all what you want is the outline.
If you want to fill, you can use the fillPoly function to fill the contours directly with specified color, and then use the binary filter to make all pixels with that color while and others black.